# TypeError while adding key/value pair to hash during iteration

Tags: ruby, hash

I think I misunderstand hashes as concerns the code below:

```
require 'rest-client'
require 'json'

def get_from_mashable
  res = JSON.load(RestClient.get('http://mashable.com/stories.json'))

  res["hot"].map do |story|
    s = {title: story["title"], category: story["channel"]}
    add_upvotes(s)
  end
 end

def add_upvotes(hash)
  hash.map do |story|
    temp = {upvotes: 1}
    if story[:category] == "Tech"
      temp[:upvotes] *= 10
    elsif story[:category] == "Business"
      temp[:upvotes] *= 5
    else
      temp[:upvotes] *= 3
    end
  end
  hash.each {|x| puts x}
end

get_from_mashable()
```

I get the following error from this:

```
ex_teddit_api_news.rb:16:in `[]': no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer (TypeError)
```

I am trying to add an `upvotes` key and corresponding integer value into each hash created from the JSON object in `get_from_mashable`. In the loop, I am not trying to erase the content of each hash and replace it with only the new key/value pair, which I have a feeling I may be doing.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have not provided sufficient information, we can only guess, but most likely, `story` is an array, not a hash.

Comment: That seems reasonably clear from the OP's code, `hash.map do |story|` will result in `story` iterating `[ key, value ]`

Comment: @NeilSlater You are right. But the OP hasn't put enough effort to explain.

Answer (score 1):

This returns an array of hash, where each hash has the keys title, category and upvotes.

```
require 'rest-client'
require 'json'

def get_from_mashable
  res = JSON.load(RestClient.get('http://mashable.com/stories.json'))

  res["hot"].map do |story|
    s = {title: story["title"], category: story["channel"], upvotes: get_upvotes(story["channel"]) }
  end
end



def get_upvotes(category)
    case category
      when "Tech" 
       10
      when "Business"  
       5
      else  
       3
     end
end

get_from_mashable()
```